# Веб-программирование и web-разработка

Tags: предложение, метки, использование-метки

Есть две метки: [веб-программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [web-разработка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0).

1. Видимо их нужно синонимизировать.
2. Не худо бы дописать руководство к объединенной метке. Например, мне кажется сомнительным употребление этих меток в [подобных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/493965/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-mex-%D0%B2-wcf-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D0%B5) [вопросах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494809/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-wcf-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1).

Answer (score 7):

Эти метки надо удалить.​​​​​​​

Comment: Поддерживаю, метки слишком обобщённые.

Comment: Как насчет вопросов о веб-программировании без привязки к языку?

Comment: @Nofate приведите, пожалуйста, пример вопроса.

Comment: Не надо удалять.

Comment: @Nofate [tag:http]? [tag:браузер]? Любой приходящий мне в голову вопрос касается чего-то более конкретного.

Comment: вообще, пожалуй вы правы. слишком абстрактно

Comment: @NickVolynkin решение-то какое? Кто займется удалением?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Как обычно: кому не лень, тот и займётся.

Answer (score -2):

Синонимизировать к [web-разработка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0).