# Долой безликие метки [веб-программирование] и подобные

Tags: предложение, метки, удаление-метки

Подобный вопрос [уже поднимался](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2577/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-web-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0), но с предложением синонимизировать.

Под эти метки можно отнести существенную часть вопросов на сайте. Более подробная аргументация [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4340/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9).

---

Предлагаю удалить метки [веб-программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), [web-разработка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) (автор предложения @alexolut). Также предлагаю сжечь [web](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web). Возможно найдутся какие-то ещё.

---

Если вдруг примется решение их оставить, то давайте сделаем их синонимами.

Comment: @alexolut Извините, исправил.

Comment: Про [tag:web], кстати, вопрос спорный. В исходном комменте я не утверждал, что хочу её сжечь.

Comment: @alexolut Хорошо, исправил.

Comment: В итоге все три метки слиты на веб-программирование, и там 4к вопросов.

Answer (score -1):

Тег [web-разработка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0) нужен для общих вопросов по веб-разработке.

Не все общие вопросы плохие, а на не общие и не надо её лепить.

Comment: Хорошо, есть примеры вопросов с меткой [tag:web-разработка], без которой данный вопрос будет неполноценен?