# Меткам нужно время

Tags: обсуждение, нытьё

В топ меты попало 3 свежесозданных вопроса по меткам за час:

- [Долой безликие метки [веб-программирование] и подобные](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4339/178988)
- [Долой метку [software] и подобные безликие метки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4338/178988)
- [Должна ли метка быть однозначной?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4340/178988)

Давайте так больше не делать и давать людям время почитать и подумать?

Comment: а можно просто по тихому выжигать неугодных каленым железом :-)